# window.onbeforeunload shouldnt work when refresh the page with clicked button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, input

I have a sign up form in my page. So I want when the user accidentally refresh or close tab or browser and the visitor has written something in someone

```
<input type="text" placeholder="something"/>
```

then appear:

```
return "you have to fill the whole form";
```

Everything works, but I have a problem with the button!
The button has no **Javascript** and no **jQuery** function.
My PHP-script checks all these inputs and refresh the page.
The visitor fill the whole form and click signup and appear.

```
return "you have to fill the whole form";
```

This shouldn't be like this and I cannot share the PHP code because of the security of the webpage.

Maybe can I fix this with the right JS or jQuery code!

**jsFiddle Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/dV9sU/9/

PS: Sorry for my English.

Comment: @bjb568 well this is really helpful but it is better when it dosent apear anything. 
Is there such a function?

Comment: you have set it up so that when you click on it, the alert appears.
I want neither an alert or a return, I just want the page to be refreshed without something appears.
You understand?

Comment: no it doesnt work, check this with my Fiddle link

Comment: i've no more code - except the php code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44743/discussion-between-selfproblemmade-and-bjb568)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/dV9sU/11/

```
<input type="submit" name="sign_in" value="Registrieren" class="success_button" onclick="alert(onbeforeunload());" />
```