# window.onbeforeunload only works after i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

note: i  see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982724/window-onbeforeunload-shouldnt-work-when-refresh-the-page-with-clicked-button) but the problem is not the same.

I have one page named  login_check.cfm and this page do a location.href to home.cfm

inside the home.cfm i have this code

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() { window.history.go(0); };
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() { window.history.forward(1); };
</script>
```

my intention is to prohibit the User to use the back button, and its work, but only a do a refresh or use a link to do refresh. 
the problem is my page is 90% ajax based and the most off the user go back to login page when they clicked backbutton.

use Document ready() make no difference.

suggestions ?

Comment: Lol "QuestionsOverflow" :D

Comment: I'd suggest to use `location.replace` instead `location.href`.

Comment: i get a blank page using this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this old [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript) where [rohit416](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1386680/rohit416) give a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12381873/3083901) and it still works

```
(function ($, global) {

    var _hash = "!",
    noBackPlease = function () {
        global.location.href += "#";

        setTimeout(function () {
            global.location.href += "!";
        }, 50);
    };

    global.setInterval(function () {
        if (global.location.hash != _hash) {
            global.location.hash = _hash;
        }
    }, 100);

    global.onload = function () {
        noBackPlease();

        // disables backspace on page except on input fields and textarea.
        $(document.body).keydown(function (e) {
            var elm = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
            if (e.which == 8 && elm !== 'input' && elm  !== 'textarea') {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            // stopping event bubbling up the DOM tree..
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    }

})(jQuery, window);
```